# Determining uniform convergence of a sequence of exponential functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am given the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=e^{-nx^2}$ on $[-10,10]$. I must find the pointwise limit function $f(x)$ and decide whether convergence is uniform. If it is, I must find a $B_n$ such that  $f_n(x) \leq B_n$ for all $n$ and $B_n \rightarrow 0$. If not, I must find an $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $x_n$ such that $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$

I determined the pointwise limit function to be $f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x = 0 \newline 
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}$

However, I am having trouble with the second step. I presume it is not uniformly convergent, since it will have a jump as $x \rightarrow 0$. I do not know what $\epsilon$ to work with here. I tried solving it for $x_n$ but I got something like $f_n(x_n) \leq -\epsilon$ which doesn't seem right.

Comment: You can basically pick a value for $\varepsilon$, e.g., $\varepsilon=\frac 12$. Observe that $f_n(0)=1>\frac 12$ for all $n$ and $f_n(10)<\frac 12$. Since $f_n$ is continuous, there must be some $x_n\in(0,10)$ such that $f_n(x_n)=\frac 12$. Now you should be able to solve for $x_n$.

Comment: So would any value for 0 < epsilon < 1 work?

Comment: Strictly speaking you need that $\varepsilon > f_1(10)$. Otherwise, the desired statement is only true for all but finitely many $n$. Alternatively, you can let $x_n$ be the minimum of $10$ and the solution of $f_n(y)=\varepsilon$. But yes, besides technicalities, any $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ will work.

Comment: I seem to run into an issue where I am taking the square root of a negative number when solving for Xn since I will be taking the ln of a number less than one

Comment: But you also have another minus to make up for it: $e^{-nx^2}=\frac 12$ $\Rightarrow -nx^2=\log(\frac 12)$ $\Rightarrow x^2=-\frac 1n\log(\frac 12)>0$.

Comment: ah thank you, I was applying ln inside the absolute values.